# Issue with getting current position of camera in google_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

I'm a novice in Flutter, and I encountered an issue with google maps plugin. I watched a couple of tutorials in order to get the current position of the camera and Most of them was using **GoogleMapController.cameraPosition.target**. I think they deleted this method from the controller(Since it is still on the development stage). Is there any other way of getting the current position of the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `google_maps_flutter` package:

The `GoogleMap` widget have the `onCameraMove` function that returns the `CameraPosition` while dragging the map or moving the camera.

To do this, you'll need to create a callback function called `_getCameraPosition(CameraPosition cameraPosition` which will be invoked when `onCameraMove` is called. For example:

```
void _getCameraPosition(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
   // You can do whatever you want with cameraPosition here
   log("cameraPosition: " + cameraPosition.target.toString());
}
```

Then, you'll need to put the `_getCameraPosition` function to the `onCameraMove` field on `GoogleMap` widget, like this:

```
GoogleMap(
   onCameraMove: _getCameraPosition,    // pass it here
   onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
   initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
       target: LatLng(-33.86882, 151.209296),
       zoom: 12,
   ),
 ),
```

As a result, you will get a `LatLng` value in the debug console. For example:

```
cameraPosition: LatLng(-33.8940124943736, 151.2027569487691)
```